# Vee validate return true, but should return false

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Im using Vuetify, and have a form where im using VeeValidate for form validation... 
When im using this:

```
this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
            console.log("result form", result);
            //result ? this.onSubmit() : scrollTo(0, 250);
        });
```

It always returns true, even if the validation on my input field isn't valid...
The input looks like:

```
<v-textarea
    filled
    name="string"
    :label="placeholderText"
    auto-grow
    single-line
    :placeholder="placeholderText"
    v-model="answer"
    :required="isRequired"
    v-validate:computedProp="checkRequired"
    :error-messages="errors.collect('string')"
    data-vv-name="string"
    :hint="hintText"
    @blur="updateAnswer"
></v-textarea>
```

The code for the input component:

```
export default {
$_veeValidate: {
    validator: 'new'
},
name: 'String',
props: {
    placeholderText: {
        default: 'Add a value'
    },
    hintText: {
        default: 'Add a value'
    },
    isRequired: {
        default: true
    }
},
data: () => ({
    answer: ''
}),
computed: {
    checkRequired() {
        return this.isRequired ? 'required' : ''
    }
},
methods: {
    updateAnswer() {
        this.$validator.validateAll();
        this.$emit('updateAnswer', this.answer);
    }
}
```

}

Im calling this.$validator.validateAll() in another component... The input component is a standalone component... I have it all wrappet in a form tag, and running the validate function on a submit

Comment: Isn't `checkRequired` always going to be true? 'required' is true as well as an empty string? Why not `return this.isRequird ? true : false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choice:

1. Pass to the component the v-validate from the [$attrs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance)
2. Inject the $validator to the component

### Parent

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    YourComponent
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      $validator: this.$validator
    };
  },
```

### Child

```
 $_veeValidate: {
    validator: "new"
  },
  inject: ["$validator"],
  name: "String",
```

You can also simplify your html code, see the [VeeValidate Syntax](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/syntax.html#rules-in-practice)

### Html

```
v-validate="{ required: this.isRequired }"
```

And you can safely remove

```
:required="isRequired"
```

Comment: Doesnt quite work... It does the validation correct on blur, but still not when I do the submit.... Maybe it's because it's not a direct child, but a grand, grand, grand child... 3-4 levels down...

Comment: Provide / Inject the `$validator` down to the child components.